# Hide HTML Elements when printing in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: html, css, printing, outlook

I'd like to hide a table in my HTML formatted messages when printing. It's got a class="noprint" attribute. Other well mannered mail clients respect CSS rules and media queries, and for them all I need to do is add a basic stylesheet:

```
@media print {
     .noprint { display: none; }
}
```

I see from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562147/override-css-and-html-styles-in-outlook-2007-word-2007) that Outlook & Word don't support media queries.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Nope, I do not think there is a workaround.

Comment: There is no workaround. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110928/outlook-2007-10-13-style-media-print-work-around

Answer (score 3):

There is a conditional css workaround for this. Add this code to your main css file.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .noprint { display: none; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's helpful, but I'd still like to display the content on screen, just not on print.

Answer (score 0):

`mso-hide:all` on its own won't work. It is a vendor specific property of the Microsoft Word engine. In order for the hide on desktop/show on mobile situation to work you need additional properties. Here are some additional properties you need to use:

```
*[class="hide"] {
    max-height:0; /* Gmail*/
    display:none; /* Generic*/
    mso-hide:all; /* Outlook clients*/
    overflow:hidden; /* Generic */
    font-size:0; /* Be careful with this one, only use if absolutely required */
}
```

Then in a media query you'd want to override any of the values set to the opposite of hiding.

Also note with `mso-hide:all`, that if you are trying to hide content within the table cell that includes nested tables, you must apply this property to any and all nested tables within as well.